# How can I handle, using RestKit in iOS, a RESTful server sending JSON without rootkey?

Tags: ios, json, post, response, restkit

I successfully POST to a RESTful service but it is sending back the follow json response;

```
 T restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:202 bodyAsString: {"Successful":true,"Message":"We have received 9138 message(s)","Data":null}
```

(from RestKit debugger/logger).
As you can see there is no rootkey in that JSON.
Now RestKit complains when it tries to map this using the following code;

```
RKObjectMapping *serverResponseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ServerReply class]];
[serverResponseMapping setRootKeyPath:@""]; //tried without this and with a value but no change!
[serverResponseMapping mapKeyPath:@"Success" toAttribute:@"success"];
[serverResponseMapping mapKeyPath:@"Message" toAttribute:@"message"];
[serverResponseMapping mapKeyPath:@"Data" toAttribute:@"data"];
[[manager mappingProvider] addObjectMapping:serverResponseMapping];
```

I get the following error from Restkit when it tries to map this;

```
W restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMapper.m:87 Adding mapping error: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''
```

Just to highlight 
`-[serverResponseMapping setRootKeyPath:@""];` **//tried without this line of code and also with a value but no change!**

Can anyone tell me how to get round this as I don't think I'll be able to get the server changed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it, so I thought I'd update this on the off chance someone else finds it useful.
If you use the block construct of the RKObjectManager postObject message you can specify the receiving object for the return message in the ObjectLoader;

```
[manager postObject:thePostMsgObj usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader){
    loader.targetObject = theResponseObj;
    loader.delegate = self;
    loader.objectMapping = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[response Class]];
}];
```